# Another way to display JS on PHP page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am retrieving some information from Google's API and placing them in a single variable, and then inserting them to a div in the DOM like so:

```
$(function() {
    // Load the info via Google's API
    $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/103039534797695934641/activities/public?maxResults=5&key=AIzaSyBaDZGM-uXuHc-VZZ2DINzVBcIDMN_54zg", function(data) {

        // Variable to hold the HTML we'll generate
        var html = '';
        // how many posts we're displaying on the page
        var numberOfPosts = 3;

        // Loop over the results, generating the HTML for each <li> item
        for (var i=0; i<numberOfPosts; i++) {
            html += '<article>';
            html += '<img src="'+data.items[i].actor.image.url+'">';
            html += '<p>'+data.items[i].title+'</p>';
            html += '<p>'+data.items[i].published+'</p>';
            html += '</article>';
        }

        // Insert the generated HTML to the DOM
        $('.google-posts-container').html(html);
    });
});
```

My question is: is there a way to store every piece of information in each of its own variable, and then get the information individually by echoing the variable? So i dont have to hardcode all that HTML.

Comment: do you mean that you want to make an html template with placeholders instead of concatenating html strings using javascript?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with php... if you mean the template is in php, you can retrieve the template then for each post use the template to generate an article for each post.

Comment: Sounds like you want a template library... let the flame wars begin on choice. I'll fire the first shot with http://handlebarsjs.com.

Comment: But do you want it server side or in JS? You can also call the API with PHP, create a template file then parse it with the variables and output the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

back in the days I would do:

```
<div id="google-posts-container">
    <article>
        <img src="{{image}}">
        <p>{{title}}</p>
        <p>{{published}}</p>
    </article>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// render a template (replace variables and return html)
function renderTemplate(tmpl, data){
    for (k in data){
        while(tmpl.indexOf('{{'+k+'}}') > -1){
            tmpl = tmpl.replace('{{'+k+'}}', data[k]);
        }
    }
    return tmpl;
}
$(function(){
    // our template
    var template = $('#google-posts-container').html();
    $('#google-posts-container').html(''); // or clear()

    $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/103039534797695934641"
        +"/activities/public"
        +"?maxResults=5&key=AIzaSyBaDZGM-uXuHc-VZZ2DINzVBcIDMN_54zg", function(data) {
        // Variable to hold the HTML we'll generate
        var html = '';
        // how many posts we're displaying on the page
        var numberOfPosts = 3;

        // Loop over the results, generating the HTML for each <li> item
        for (var i=0; i<numberOfPosts; i++) {
            html += renderTemplate(template, {
                image : data.items[i].actor.image.url,
                title : data.items[i].title,
                publish : data.items[i].published
            });
        }

        // Insert the generated HTML to the DOM
        $('.google-posts-container').html(html);
    });

});
</script>
```

nowadays I use angularjs

Comment: You should probably explain that this is called "micro-templating" to give the OP a head start on a good Google search. +1 because this is the simplest solution without including another monolithic library.

Answer (score 0):

About comment by 'galchen' - don't use angular.js for serious &(or) big projects. Just look at source code.
(can't add sub comment, thats why i wrote to main branch)